# Jest TS test that imports ESM file has ReferenceError on exports

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, es6-modules

Typescript test files work perfectly using `ts-jest` transform (Windows 11, jest 29.4.2, node 18.13.0) if I don't import files from my application.

But if I import a file from my application (ESM js file compiled from typescript source) it fails with the error: `ReferenceError: exports is not defined` on the import line:

```
import {Configuration} from "../server/ServerConfiguration.js";

describe("ServerConfiguration", () => {

    test("Defaults", () => {

        const sc = Configuration.getInstance(true).configuration;

        expect(sc.verboseLevel).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

There is no `exports` anywhere in the compiled js files. Nothing changes removing extension from imported file.

The test script is: `"test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest --config config/jest.config.json --runInBand"`.

I tried to add `exports` definition to the test file this way:

```
let exports: unknown;
void exports;
```

But the test simply hangs without any error.

The `jest.config.json` contains:

```
{
  "rootDir": "..",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "verbose": true,
  "testMatch": ["**/tests/*.test.ts"],
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "js"],
  "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [".ts"],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": ["!../common/", "!../server/", "!./"],
  "transform": {
    "\\.ts$": ["ts-jest", {
      "tsconfig": "tests/tsconfig.json",
      "diagnostics": {"ignore": [1343]}
      }]
  }
}
```

Anyone had the same problem (and found a way to solve it)?
Thanks!
mario

**More info:** another test that runs perfectly without defining the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable, now fails with the same error on the `import os from "node:os";` line. So I try to upgrade node to version 19 and see what happens.

Comment: first try removing .js ext from your import

Comment: Done, no change. I have to dismount the imported file to see if there is something specific that causes the error. Stay tuned.

Comment: Same error with node 19

Comment: Same error with `import {v4} from "uuid"` and in test only `expect(v4()).toBeDefined()`, so no references to my code.